# How do I prove all constants to some exponential power belong to little-o of some function

Tags: algorithm, math, little-o

I'm trying to prove that *c<sup>2n</sup> = o((loglog n)<sup>n</sup>)* (That's little-o) for any constant c. I understand that we can prove one function grows at a smaller rate than the other by taking the limit as *n* approaches infinity, and I can very easily pick some arbitrary integer value for *c* and show that indeed *((loglog n)<sup>n</sup>)* grows at a faster rate. But how do I prove this to be true for any constant *c*?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math, not programming. Try math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about CS theory, rather than programming.  It might be a better fit on cs.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to prove that for any choice of c, the value of

> lim<sub>n → ∞</sub> (c<sup>2n</sup> / (log log n)<sup>n</sup>) = 0

Notice that for any choice of c that

> > lim<sub>n → ∞</sub> (c<sup>2n</sup> / (log log n)<sup>n</sup>)
>
> = lim<sub>n → ∞</sub> (c<sup>2</sup> / log log n)<sup>n</sup>

This limit is 0 because once log log n > c<sup>2</sup>, you're raising a value less than one to the power of n, which will quickly drop to zero.

Hope this helps!

Comment: To be pedantic, I think we just need to prove that the limit is less than 1 rather than equal to 0, although proving that it's equal to 0 has proven that it's less than 1.

Comment: @wookie919 From what I recall, it's not sufficient to prove that the limit is less than one. For example, the limit of n / 2n as n tends to infinity is 1 / 2, but n != o(2n).